# Finding shared data between two excel sheets

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet that has lists of part numbers at 2 locations. I need to compare the 2 tabs and create a list of part numbers that the sheets have in common. They are formatted the same, but part numbers are not arranged in the same order and not all values are on both sheets. I'm not sure what would be the best function to use here whether vlookup or an index match. What would you recommend?

Comment: vlookup is pretty simple to set up, i would try that one first

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/vlookup-from-another-sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a vlookup with iferror to get a column that would tell me if the data point was in the other sheet. Then sorted that column based of the ones that didnt have an error.

=iferror(Vlookup(a2,Othersheet'A:G,7,False),"No Match")